# Tracking instantaneous chages

Tags: text-editing

is there any package that tracks changes made on an instantaneous basis?  That is, just like handwriting captures edits, I would like to see all the changes as a buffer is developing.  So, there is no separate ediff or compare call to make, but live tracking of all the deletions, backstrokes, etc.  Any pointers?  Thanks, -jay

[image]

Comment: The question is not very clear. Track all editing changes how? What kind of tracking? Try to specify more clearly what you have in mind.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear.  Let's say I type a few words and then go back and edit a few of them, I would like to see the changes I just made. So, if I changed "tell" to "well" I should see the "t" changed to "w."  Does that make sense?  Thanks.

Comment: You should "see" it how? If you have some kind of visualisation in mind, perhaps you could show or describe it in the question. I'm having trouble imagining anything like this which isn't rapidly going to become all but unmanageable. Are you talking about tracking *all* changes (essentially processing the undo list), or only tracking the differences between the current state and the saved state?

Comment: Phils: I hope the image above clarifies the question.  The tracking should show the differences between what was originally typed and subsequent edits, ideally even in an unsaved buffer.

Comment: That's helpful, but a bit simplistic. If it's tracking *all* changes, can you please show an example with multiple edits to the same piece of text? e.g. After the sequences of transitions from "demontrate" => "demonstrate" => "demoate" => "demotrate" => "demonstrate", what does the buffer look like?

Comment: Phils: plz see updated image above on your question on how the buffer might look with a sequence of edits.

Answer (score 1):

1. Command `highlight-changes-mode`:

> `highlight-changes-mode` is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
>   `hilit-chg.el`.
>
> `(highlight-changes-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle highlighting changes in this buffer (Highlight Changes mode).
>
> With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable Highlight Changes mode if `ARG`
>   is positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp,
>   enable the mode if `ARG` is omitted or `nil`.
>
> When Highlight Changes is enabled, changes are marked with a text
>   property.  Normally they are displayed in a distinctive face, but
>   command `M-x highlight-changes-visible-mode` can be used to toggle
>   this on and off.
>
> Other functions for buffers in this mode include:
>
> - `M-x highlight-changes-next-change` - move point to beginning of next change
> - `M-x highlight-changes-previous-change` - move to beginning of previous change
> - `M-x highlight-changes-remove-highlight` - remove the change face from the region
> - `M-x highlight-changes-rotate-faces` - rotate different "ages" of changes
>     through various faces.
> - `M-x highlight-compare-with-file` - mark text as changed by comparing this
>     buffer with the contents of a file
> - `M-x highlight-compare-buffers` highlights differences between two buffers.

2. Command `diff-backup` (less "instantaneous" - just a diff from the last backup):

> `diff-backup` is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `diff.el`.
>
> `(diff-backup FILE &optional SWITCHES)`
>
> Diff this file with its backup file or vice versa.
>   Uses the latest backup, if there are several numerical backups.
>   If this file is a backup, diff it with its original.
>   The backup file is the first file given to `diff`.
>   With prefix arg, prompt for diff switches.